# Extract values from two columns of a dataframe and put it in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
df = 

 A  col_1   col_45   col_3
1.0   4.0    45.0    [1, 9]
2.0   4.0    NaN     [9, 10]
3.0   49.2   10.8    [1, 10]
```

The values in `col_1` are of type float and the values in `col_3` are in a list. For every row, I want to extract the values in `col_1` and `col_3` and put it together in a list.

I tried the following:

```
df[['col_1','col_3']].astype(float).values.tolist()
```

But it threw me a Value error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`.

I would like to have a list as follows:

```
[[4.0,1.0,9.0],
 [4.0,9.0,10.0],
 [49.2,1.0,10.0]]
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: can you put your data as dict? using df.to_dict()

Comment: All elements in col_3 have size 2?

Comment: No. Some elementsjust have a size 1 and some have a size of 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert one element in `col_1` to `list` then use merge two list like `list_1 + list_2`, You can use [`pandas.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for iterate over each row:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda row: [row['col_1']] + row['col_3'], axis=1)
0      [4.0, 1, 9]
1     [4.0, 9, 10]
2    [49.2, 1, 10]
dtype: object

>>> df.apply(lambda row: [row['col_1']] + row['col_3'], axis=1).to_list()
[
    [4.0, 1, 9], 
    [4.0, 9, 10], 
    [49.2, 1, 10]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) functions to cast the `col_1` to `list` and then concatenate by `+` operator -

```
df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: [x]) + df['col_3']
```

**Output**

```
0      [4.0, 1, 9]
1     [4.0, 9, 10]
2    [49.2, 1, 10]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

The best IMO, might be to use underlying numpy array:

```
out = np.c_[df['col_1'].to_numpy(), df['col_3'].to_list()].tolist()
```

output:

```
[[4.0, 1.0, 9.0],
 [4.0, 9.0, 10.0],
 [49.2, 1.0, 10.0]]
```

If you want to keep a DataFrame:

```
pd.concat([df['col_1'], pd.DataFrame(df['col_3'].to_list())], axis=1)
```

output:

```
   col_1  0   1
0    4.0  1   9
1    4.0  9  10
2   49.2  1  10
```